# mdaemon bad mails queue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

i have been having a problem two days now...the emails are being redirected to the bad queues instead of sending them..this makes the retry queue to also have so many emails...please advice on how to stop this ...

secondly what happens if i delete the emails in the bad queue?

am using maemon vs 10.0.0.0

regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the logs to find why the emails are going to the bad queue.
If you delete those messages then they will not be delivered.

Could you provide an extract of the logs and your configuration or at least 
more info about the problem?

Comment: hea is a sample log file